# BERDecodeError when trying to verify a signature using a public key

Tags: c++, rsa, digital-signature, crypto++

I am writing a project about the AODV routing protocol in MANETs (mobile ad hoc networks) and one of things I am aiming to do is to add a digital signature to a field in one of the protocol's packets.

I am using NS3 to simulate the network which is based on C++. For the signing, I am using Crypto++'s RSA library. Basically, a node generates a public and private key pair to sign the packet, includes its public key in the packet, then sends it to another node. The receiving node then uses the public key provided in the packet to verify the signature. The public key in the packet is encoded as a hex string with `std::string` data type.

I have already confirmed that the public key is correct and the problem solely lies on decoding the public key string from hex format.

These are the functions I use to generate key pairs, sign, and verify 
(I got these from http://marko-editor.com/articles/cryptopp_sign_string/):

```
struct KeyPairHex {
  std::string publicKey;
  std::string privateKey;
};

KeyPairHex 
RoutingProtocol::RsaGenerateHexKeyPair(unsigned int aKeySize) {
  KeyPairHex keyPair;

  // PGP Random Pool-like generator
  AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

  // generate keys
  RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
  privateKey.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, aKeySize);
  RSA::PublicKey publicKey(privateKey);

  // save keys
  publicKey.Save( HexEncoder(
                    new StringSink(keyPair.publicKey)).Ref());
  privateKey.Save(HexEncoder(
                    new StringSink(keyPair.privateKey)).Ref());

  return keyPair;
}

std::string 
RoutingProtocol::RsaSignString(const std::string &aPrivateKeyStrHex,
                               const std::string &aMessage) {

  // decode and load private key (using pipeline)
  RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
  privateKey.Load(StringSource(aPrivateKeyStrHex, true,
                               new HexDecoder()).Ref());

  // sign message
  std::string signature;
  RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA>::Signer signer(privateKey);
  AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

  StringSource ss(aMessage, true,
                  new SignerFilter(rng, signer,
                    new HexEncoder(
                      new StringSink(signature))));

  return signature;
}

bool 
RoutingProtocol::RsaVerifyString(const std::string &aPublicKeyStrHex,
                                 const std::string &aMessage,
                                 const std::string &aSignatureStrHex) {

  // decode and load public key (using pipeline)

  RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
  publicKey.Load(StringSource(aPublicKeyStrHex, true,
                              new HexDecoder()).Ref());


  // decode signature
  std::string decodedSignature;
  StringSource ss(aSignatureStrHex, true,
                  new HexDecoder(
                    new StringSink(decodedSignature)));

  // verify message
  bool result = false;
  RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);
  StringSource ss2(decodedSignature + aMessage, true,
                   new SignatureVerificationFilter(verifier,
                     new ArraySink((byte*)&result, sizeof(result))));

  return result;
}
```

I am using a keysize of 384. Here is the public key:

```
304A300D06092A864886F70D01010105000339003036023100CC112A0E007C6329F813BC96498AFE
DF580EE4F708C2A923F6C6257FA4CC5FE2BA711C75CDE02036839E67C9B62720B3020111
```

There is no problem with signing the message. However, when loading the key from the string I keep getting an error.

The error I am getting is:

```
terminate called after throwing instance of 'BerDecodeErr' what(): BER decode error
```

Answer (score 0):

The Crypto++ code looks OK. I think the private key is ill-formed:

```
$ echo -n 304A300D06092A864886F70D01010105000339003036023100CC112A0E007C6329F813
BC96498AFEDF580EE4F708C2A923F6C6257FA4CC5FE2BA711C75CDE02036839E67C9B62720B30201
11 | hex -d | dumpasn1 -

  0  74: SEQUENCE {
  2  13:   SEQUENCE {
  4   9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
 15   0:     NULL
       :     }
 17  57:   BIT STRING
       :     30 36 02 31 00 CC 11 2A 0E 00 7C 63 29 F8 13 BC
       :     96 49 8A FE DF 58 0E E4 F7 08 C2 A9 23 F6 C6 25
       :     7F A4 CC 5F E2 BA 71 1C 75 CD E0 20 36 83 9E 67
       :     C9 B6 27 20 B3 02 01 11
       :   }
```

And then the inner `BIT_STRING`:

```
$ echo -n 3036023100CC112A0E007C6329F813BC96498AFEDF580EE4F708C2A923F6C6257FA4CC
5FE2BA711C75CDE02036839E67C9B62720B3020111 | hex -d | dumpasn1 -

  0  54: SEQUENCE {
  2  49:   INTEGER
       :     00 CC 11 2A 0E 00 7C 63 29 F8 13 BC 96 49 8A FE
       :     DF 58 0E E4 F7 08 C2 A9 23 F6 C6 25 7F A4 CC 5F
       :     E2 BA 71 1C 75 CD E0 20 36 83 9E 67 C9 B6 27 20
       :     B3
 53   1:   INTEGER 17
       :   }
```

That looks like a public key, not a private key. A RSA public key is `{n,e}`, while a RSA private key in short form is `{n,e,d}`.

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere around here in your real code. `aPrivateKeyStrHex` is not a private key:

```cpp
// generate keys
RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
privateKey.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, aKeySize);
RSA::PublicKey publicKey(privateKey);

// save keys
publicKey.Save( HexEncoder(
                new StringSink(keyPair.publicKey)).Ref());
privateKey.Save( HexEncoder(
                 new StringSink(keyPair.privateKey)).Ref());
```

There are some pages in the Crypto++ wiki that cover RSA, like [RSA Cryptography](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography) and [RSA Signature Schemes](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes). But I think your Crypto++ code is OK.

---

Here is a minimal reproducer, if interested:

```cpp
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "rsa.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

const std::string strKey = 
    "304A300D06092A864886F70D01010105000339003036023100CC112A0E00"
    "7C6329F813BC96498AFEDF580EE4F708C2A923F6C6257FA4CC5FE2BA711C"
    "75CDE02036839E67C9B62720B3020111";

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
    StringSource key(strKey, true, new HexDecoder);
    privateKey.Load(key);

    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    if (privateKey.Validate(prng, 3) != true)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to validate private key");

    std::cout << std::hex << privateKey.GetModulus() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << privateKey.GetPublicExponent() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << privateKey.GetPrivateExponent() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```